# How do I get rid of click-once?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, clickonce

I've taken over a project that uses ClickOnce deployment, but we made a decision to drop it and rather do it thru a Nullsoft installer.

I've gone through the project properties and unselected everything that had something to do with ClickOnce, but still the exe file nags me about "Program indentity has not been set" or something like that (the message language isnt english so sorry for possible crappy translation)

Anyone knows how I can get rid of ClickOnce 100% for my application?

Comment: +1, I've felt the pain before. I *think* I solved it by manually removing every trace of the project from the `.csproj` file, but I'm not sure if that works.

Comment: if possible, create a new project file and add all files to it and use that project instead.

Comment: Did you take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923607/remove-clickonce-from-a-winforms-app ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way would probably be to create a new clean solution and copy the needed source files in there.
Also if there's some traces left you can see those when building, you'll get errors.

I've never used it, but I think you should firstly remove the references to it in the project, and you should check the publish tab in the properties of the project.

Answer (score 8):

You can uncheck the box in the Security tab of your project properties that says "Enable ClickOnce security settings" and uncheck the box in the Signing tab that says "Sign the ClickOnce manifests." I suppose you could blank out the info in the Options dialog as well.

Note that none of the ClickOnce stuff is used unless you actually publish your application, so having it in there doesn't hurt anything.