# Why does the "Sign the ClickOnce manifests" checkbox keep defaulting to checked on build?

Tags: c#, msbuild, vsto, clickonce

Closely related to [Sign the ClickOnce manifests checkbox keeps defaulting to checked on publish](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6022433/1751715). None of the answers listed in this question have assisted me.

I have two projects in my solution, as well as other reference projects. One project is a C# `Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF)` (output type Windows Application), and when I uncheck "Sign the ClickOnce manifests" it remains unchecked after being built.

The second project, which is also the startup project, is a `Visual Studio Tools for Office (VSTO)` project (output type defaults to Class Library and cannot be changed). When I uncheck "Sign the ClickOnce manifests" in it and then build the solution (or just the project), the option is checked again *after* the entire build process completes.

I am not familiar with the XML data in the .csproj file, but I have found a few things that might be related:

### 1.

In the .csproj file for the VSTO project, there is a comment section which states:

> ```
> This section enables pre- and post-build steps. However, in VSTO use
> MSBuild tasks instead of these properties.
> ```

The section defines `<SignManifests>`, `<SignAssembly>`, and `<ManifestCertificateThumbprint>`. The first two are false. The second has some unique key.

### 2.

After finding the comment about MSBuild tasks, I later found:

```
<!-- Include additional build rules for an Office application add-in. -->
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\OfficeTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.targets" />
```

And this is a very large file with multiple references to signing and such. The project in which the Signing option remains unchecked **does not** have this `<Import Project>` line in its .csproj file.

### Issue

Now, I'm not fully aware of what the .targets file is all about and am unwilling to go butchering it in search of a solution until I know what I'm after. Could this file be the cause of my problem? If so, how can I modify it to stop it from getting in my way?
 If not, has anyone encountered this before that can provide a solution?

### Edit:

I just read [How to not sign a ClickOnce manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/q/229373/1751715), which talks again about publishing. I am still curious if I can turn it off of my builds. I have no qualms about signing the application when I publish it, but I would prefer to build it without the default occurring.

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? I am also facing the same problem. Don't know why it keeps re-checking the "sign the clickonce manifest" inspite of my target framework being .Net 3.5

Comment: @HarshMaurya sadly I've left this project and issue behind, and as far as I recall I never even found a work around.

Answer (score 9):

Here's an article by a VSTO team member. http://web.archive.org/web/20090604042157/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/vsto/archive/2009/04/29/signing-and-re-signing-manifests-in-clickonce.aspx

The explanation is that VSTO requires signing for ClickOnce deployments, because the add-in must run under a heightened security model.  The article goes into much more detail.

Comment: Yet another valuable MSDN resource which has disappeared into the Microsoft black hole. Why do they keep doing this after so many years?

Comment: Thanks for concise summary ;)